# Submit form with data values inserted from AJAX in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, laravel-5

I have the following section of html:

```
<div class="box-body" style="display:none;" id="claimFreightDetails">
                    <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="pulledProNumber" name="pulledProNumber"><br>
                    <strong>Origin Information</strong><br>
                    <textarea disabled class="form-control" id="claimFreightOrigin" name="claimFreightOrigin"></textarea><br>
                    <strong>Consignee Information</strong><br>
                    <textarea disabled class="form-control" id="claimFreightConsignee" name="claimFreightConsignee"></textarea><br>
                    <strong>Weight</strong>
                    <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="claimWeight" name="claimWeight"><br>
                    <strong>Pieces Count</strong><br>
                    <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="claimPieces" name="claimPieces"><br>
            </div>
```

Now, I have an AJAX POST request where the response inserts the returned data into those fields and textareas:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#pullDetails', function() {
        $('#freightBillDetails').removeClass('hidden'); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/carrier/claims/pullDetails',
            data: {
                num: $('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.details != undefined) {
                        console.log('success');
                        var results = JSON.parse(data.details);
                            $('#pulledProNumber').val(results.SearchResults[0].SearchItem);
                            $('#claimWeight').val(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Weight);
                            $('#claimPieces').val(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Pieces);
                            $("#claimFreightOrigin").html(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name + '&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Address1 +'('+results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Address2+')&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.City + ', '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.State + ' '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.PostalCode);
                            $("#claimFreightConsignee").html(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Name + '&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Address1 +'('+results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Address2+')&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.City + ', '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.State + ' '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.PostalCode);

                            $('#openInvoicesOverlay').html('');
                            $('#openInvoicesOverlay').removeClass('overlay');

                            $('#claimFreightDetails').show();

                    }else{
                        console.log('failed');
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.details['SearchResults'].SearchItem); 
                    }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, when I go to submit the form that surrounds this (many more fields, this section is just pulled through an API from a Third-Party), all of the data fields except the ones that are referenced in the AJAX are included in the POST request for the overall form.

Comment: why is all the input field and text area **disabled** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also remove disabled property after you get ajax response using this

`$('.YourDisabledInput').prop("disabled", false);`

here is your solution:

```
 <script>
     $(document).on('click', '#pullDetails', function() {
            $('#freightBillDetails').removeClass('hidden'); 
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: '/carrier/claims/pullDetails',
                data: {
                    num: $('input[name=proNumber]').val(),
                    _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.details != undefined) {
                            console.log('success');
                            var results = JSON.parse(data.details);
                                $('#pulledProNumber').val(results.SearchResults[0].SearchItem);
                                $('#claimWeight').val(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Weight);
                                $('#claimPieces').val(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Pieces);
                                $("#claimFreightOrigin").html(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Name + '&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Address1 +'('+results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.Address2+')&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.City + ', '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.State + ' '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Origin.PostalCode);
                                $("#claimFreightConsignee").html(results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Name + '&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Address1 +'('+results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.Address2+')&#013;&#010;'+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.City + ', '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.State + ' '+ results.SearchResults[0].Shipment.Consignee.PostalCode);

                                $('#openInvoicesOverlay').html('');
                                $('#openInvoicesOverlay').removeClass('overlay');

                                $('#claimFreightDetails').show();

                               $('#pulledProNumber').prop("disabled", false);
                               $('#claimWeight').prop("disabled", false);
                               $('#claimPieces').prop("disabled", false);
                               $('#claimFreightOrigin').prop("disabled", false);
                               $('#claimFreightConsignee').prop("disabled", false);


                        }else{
                            console.log('failed');
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log(data.details['SearchResults'].SearchItem); 
                        }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the the `.val` to `.attr('value')` as laravel is pulling from the DOM and jQuery .val doesnt reflect there.

you can check this link
[jQuery changing form values not affecting the DOM](https://www.willis-owen.co.uk/jquery-changing-form-values-not-affecting-the-dom/)

also you can test it on [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)

Answer (score 0):

**disabled** input fields will not be submitted with the form. That's the behaviour of disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were using the wrong name for input.
There is no input name "proNumber". In the HTML it is "pulledProNumber".
And also the field is disabled too.
Please update your code and see if it fix the problem.